# Swift - Secp256k1 compute common secret

Tags: swift, cryptography, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

I'm after a way to generate a common secret using the secp256k1 EC. I tried with https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt/ but doesn't support the secp256k1 curve.

I would need to do something like this:

```
let pairOne = generateKeyPair()
let pairTwo = generateKeyPair()

let sharedOne = computeSharedSecret(privateKey: pairOne.privateKey, publicKey: pairTwo.publicKey)
let sharedTwo = computeSharedSecret(privateKey: pairTwo.privateKey, publicKey: pairOne.publicKey)

XCTAssertEqual(sharedOne, sharedTwo)
```

Do you know any library to do it?

Comment: Hello, did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no